# Chef: Refactor Jenkins security script to own recipe file

Tags: security, jenkins, chef-infra, cookbook

I am currently using [Chef's Jenkins supermarket cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/jenkins) to deploy an instance of Jenkins. As part of that deployment, my recipe includes installing Jenkins, installing specific plugin versions, enabling security and creating an Administrator account for Jenkins.

I'm currently using a single recipe file for this. The script that is executed to enable security and create the Administrator account is as follows:

```
 jenkins_script 'activate global security' do
  command <<-EOH.gsub(/^ {4}/, '')
      import jenkins.model.*
      import hudson.security.*

      def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()

      def hudsonRealm = new HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm(false)
      hudsonRealm.createAccount("Administrator","administrator_passwd")
      instance.setSecurityRealm(hudsonRealm)
      instance.save()

      def strategy = new GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy()
        strategy.add(Jenkins.ADMINISTER, "Administrator")
        instance.setAuthorizationStrategy(strategy)

      instance.save()
  EOH

  notifies :restart, 'runit_service[jenkins]', :immediately

 end
```

The script activates security, creates the Jenkins Administrator user with a password, and then restarts the Jenkins instance. From what I understand, the jenkins_script resource executes Java or Groovy command against the Jenkins master, and is not idempotent.

As the script is not idempotent, if the recipe is run on the node subsequent times after the initial run, the chef-client run fails as security is already enabled and the Administrator user has already been created.

My thoughts are to move this security enablement script to its' own recipe file, and then specify the recipe for security in the node's run list if enabling security is required. If security has already been enabled, we simple don't add / remove the security recipe from the run list.

- Is this a sound approach to working around this problem?
- If this is a    sound approach, should it be as simple as just
  creating another ruby    file, dumping the security code in it, and
  adding it to the node's    run list after the recipe for the initial
  Jenkins install?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to restart Jenkins to configure security.

Comment: I had noticed that when I had implemented security then attempted to access my Jenkins instance without restarting, an error message explaining the user was missing the required permissions was displayed. I could not bypass this error message until manually restarting the Jenkins service, even after manually refreshing the browser when accessing Jenkins on port 8080.

Comment: Weird. IIRC it worked without problems for me. Maybe because of the broken state of the current Jenkins cookbook versions (remoting changes on Jenkins).

Answer (score 0):

When configuring security there are a few considerations you have to take into account. One is that it almost always works the first run, but you want to make sure that on repeated runs it continues to successfully apply desired changes.

There is an attribute for the `executor protocol` which defaults to `remoting` and you'll see warnings all over about using it because it is less secure and has been deprecated. Other options are `https` or `ssh`, with the latter being the option we decided to go with. If you configure it as the protocol but the SSH key provided to be used isn't associated with a user (user has to be created and then an SSH public key associated with them) then it will fall back to using `anonymous` (part of the cookbook) and so you need to ensure you either do all your "privileged" operations  like plugin installation and reconfiguration scripts before you enable authentication, or ensure you have the authentication pre-configured to request SSH so that it immediately kicks in when the authentication is turned on.